# Convert 10bit images under Linux

Tags: raw, linux

I dont even find any program for convert/view the raw file what comes from my MTK6589 phone. Automated apps are unable to get the photos, the only way is using Irfanview, but without wine its hard. So is there anyone how has ideas?

dropbox link for 2 pure raw and jpeg and 2 processed raw and jpeg. i discussed with libraw's developer, the main branch could be able to handle these raws, but the official support will come in october

[dropbox link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/zl2nytm17f4wiju/AAC6DkYeW6egsLoy-4GAWn-Qa?dl=0)

[image: irfanview settings]

Comment: Those images only have a maximum of 1024 different colours?

Comment: Which native Linux software did you try? UFRaw, RawTherapee, DarkTable...?

Comment: Can you upload a raw file from your phone on a file sharing site?

Comment: ive updated the post

Comment: So what programs did you try that didn't work?

Comment: rawtherapee, darktable, digikam, PS, gimp, xnview.
just irfanview and rawdigger are able to open these files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LibRaw supports this format (current development trunk).

So, you may use any LibRaw-based software (digiKam or so), but you'll need to update/recompile LibRaw and software that using it.